# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '' could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework

```
var baseQuery = Context.Questions.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Active && x.QuestionFoils.Any());
```

// Gets 30

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x => x.QuestionReferences.Any());
```

//Gets 2

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(
                     x => x.QuestionReferences.Any(qr => 
                     listNames.Any(name => 
                     name.FirstName == qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.FirstName &&
                     name.LastName == qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.LastName
                     )));
countCount = baseQuery.Count();
```

When I try to do any operation on the query, it gives a InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '' could not be translated.

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   'Any, ReferenceProfessor>, Professor>>( source:
>   LeftJoin, ReferenceProfessor>, Professor, Nullable,
>   TransparentIdentifier, ReferenceProfessor>, Professor>>( outer:
>   LeftJoin,
>   ReferenceProfessor, Nullable,
>   TransparentIdentifier, ReferenceProfessor>>( outer: Join, TransparentIdentifier>( outer: Where( source:
>   DbSet, predicate: (q2) =>
>   Property>(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Question
>   ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
>   EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False , "QuestionId") ==
>   Property>(q2, "QuestionId")), inner: DbSet,
>   outerKeySelector: (q2) => Property>(q2, "ReferenceId"),
>   innerKeySelector: (r) => Property>(r, "ReferenceId"),
>   resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier( Outer = o, Inner = i )), inner: DbSet,
>   outerKeySelector: (q2) => Property>(q2.Inner,
>   "ReferenceId"), innerKeySelector: (r0) => Property>(r0,
>   "ReferenceId"), resultSelector: (o, i) => new
>   TransparentIdentifier, ReferenceProfessor>( Outer = o, Inner = i )), inner:
>   DbSet, outerKeySelector: (q2) =>
>   Property>(q2.Inner, "ProfessorId"), innerKeySelector:
>   (p) => Property>(p, "ProfessorId"), resultSelector: (o,
>   i) => new
>   TransparentIdentifier, ReferenceProfessor>, Professor>( Outer = o, Inner = i )),
>   predicate: (q2) => Any( source: (Unhandled parameter:
>   __listNames_0), predicate: (name) => name.FirstName == q2.Inner.FirstName && name.LastName == q2.Inner.LastName))' could not
>   be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
>   translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
>   call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

Anything with a single table works just fine:

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x => x.QuestionCourses.Any(qc => courses.Any(name => name == qc.Course.Name)));
```

How would I rewrite the following to not throw this error?

```
  x => x.QuestionReferences.Any(qr => 
  listNames.Any(name => 
  name.FirstName == qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.FirstName &&
  name.LastName == qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.LastName
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue will be that you are trying to filter the Linq expression with an object with 2 fields (name.FirstName & name.LastName) which won't translate down to SQL. EF can translate list contains/any into IN clauses, but against a singular field/expression.

What should work:

Combine your names into a single list of strings. For instance "FirstName LastName" or "LastName, FirstName" then combine the professor name when comparing:

```
x => x.QuestionReferences.Any(qr => 
  listNames.Any(name => name == qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.FirstName 
     + " " + qr.Reference.ReferenceProfessors.Professor.LastName ))
```

Where listNames = "FirstName LastName";